# jQuery selector with exlude of element & elements children

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a div used for filtering and i want it to close when anything outside of the div is clicked.
The selector I am trying to build, basically selects all elements except a specific element and excludes its children.
Here is what I have tried, but haven't been able to get working

```
$('*:not(:has(.exclude *))').live('click', function() {HideFilter();});
```

page structure is simplified to this:

```
<div></div>
<div>
 <div></div>
 <div>
  <div class="exclude"><inputs></div>
 </div>
 <div></div>
</div>
```

so I want all of the divs, but the one and everything in the .exclude to have the event.
I have been at this for a while, I need some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried

```
$('*:not(.exclude, .exclude *)').live( ... )
```

?
[edit[ Ah I see - the problem is that even if you exclude the stuff, the events still bubble up.

Try something like this:

```
$('*').live('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).is('.exclude, .exclude *'))
    // do interesting stuff
  }
  return false;
});
```

That should stop event propagation on the excluded things without actually doing anything.

Example page: http://gutfullofbeer.net/balloon.html

*edit* update, 3 years later: the `.live()` method is at this point long-deprecated. That last example should look like this in new code:

```
$('body').on('click', '*', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).closest('.exclude').length) {
    // do interesting stuff
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: I have tried this and it still puts the events on all of the chlidren of .exclude

Comment: Are you sure that you typed it exactly like that?

Comment: yes. debugging my code i notice the selector is working correctly. Its only applying the event to the correct elements. But the elements under my div must be picking up the click also.

Answer (score 0):

how about a slightly different strategy:

close everything when anything but the div is clicked:

```
$("body").click(function(e){
  if($(e.target).hasClass("exclude")){
    //show stuff
  } else {
    //hide stuff
  }
});
```

something like that